# Cannot save array into entity (Core Data)

Tags: swift, core-data, entity-relationship

I am trying to save an array of objects into an entity's "to many" relationship of another entity (Not certain how to explain that). I swear this code was working before, but it stopped all of a sudden and I am uncertain as to why as I have not changed any code that has to do with this that I can remember. I receive a SIGABRT error that is " terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" Any input would be helpful.

```
func save (completion: (_ finished: Bool) -> ()){
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    let workout = Workout(context: managedContext)

    workout.nameOfWorkout = workoutNameLabel.text!
    workout.exercises = NSSet(array: exercises)  // problem exists on this line
    workout.numberOfExercises = Int32(exercises.count)
    print("\(workout.exercises!.count)")
    print ("\(workout.exercises!)")

    do{
        try managedContext.save()
        completion(true)
    } catch {
        debugPrint("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        completion(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do add any new DispatchQueue in your project ?

Comment: Share the complete error message

Comment: Is `exercises` an optional?  You use both `exercises.count` and  `exercises!.count` in your code sample.